# Disable debug mode in php

Tags: php, debugging

I want debugging to happen when env DEBUG is true. I want to stop debugging when DEBUG=false and prevent the code from stopping
My code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Support;

use Throwable;
use Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler;
use Whoops\Run;

class Debug
{
    private bool $status;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->status = env('DEBUG') === 'true';
    }

    public static function load($func): void
    {
        (new Debug)->debug($func);
    }

    private function debug($func): void
    {
        try {
            echo $func();
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            if ($this->status) {
                $this->handleException($e);
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
    private function handleException(Throwable $exception): void
    {
        $whoops = new Run;
        $whoops->pushHandler(new PrettyPageHandler);
        $whoops->handleException($exception);
    }
}
```

I put my code in try and nothing in catch so that nothing happens when the error occurs

Comment: "I want debugging to be done when env DEBUG is equal to true ... and I want to debug when it is equal to false" - I'm confused by those two statements

Comment: Are you sure at `env('DEBUG') === 'true';` env() returns a string with content `true`?

Comment: Instead of implementing the guard inside of the debug handler, you can instead add it where it is instantiated. `if(env('DEBUG')){new Debug();}`

Comment: Sorry, when equal to false, I want no debug to run

Comment: Yes, DEBUG is true by default
DEBUG=true

Comment: I think you need to re-throw `$e` if status is false. https://3v4l.org/39sRt. However, I'd still recommend **not** loading the Debug class at all if you aren't in debug mode. If you have a need for the class to always exist, you could also make a null/pass-through debugger that you conditionally load based on the env: https://3v4l.org/vuT4A